# ローカル(開発環境windows8.1)からGoogle App Engineのmemchacheに接続する方法はありますか？

Tags: google-app-engine, memcached

Google App Engine(PHP)を初めて触ることになったの者です。

Google App Engine Launcherを利用しwindows8.1上でテストを行っているのですが、memchachedのset()などで保存したデータは、全てローカル(windows8.1上)に保存されているようです。

ローカル(windows8.1上)ではなく契約しているGAEのmemchacheに値を保存することはできないのでしょうか？

ヘルプを見たのですが見当たりません。宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: PythonならGAE SDKに含まれているremote APIを使えば可能ですが、PHPにはまだ無いようです。なお、memcacheは永続化を目的としているわけではないので、"GAEに保存"と考えないほうがよいでしょう。前職(2014年)でGAEのmemcacheを使いましたが、突然内容が消えることがよくあります。純粋にキャッシュとして使うのがよいでしょう。

Comment: PHP版ではできないんですね。情報ありがとうございました。

Comment: いずれにせよ、保存しているデータ、という認識はされない方が良いです。memcacheは永続化を目的とされてませんので。